# What is the service that's responsible for automounting a USB drive in CentOS 6.4?

Tags: centos, usb-drive, automounting, services

I know of the legacy Linux way of mounting a USB stick or drive:  [mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72494)

But in some CentOS 6.x installations I saw, you just insert the USB stick and CentOS automagically mounts it, to `/media/<VOLUMENAME>`

This auto-sense must be handled by some kind of a daemon/service, right?

What is the name of that service and how do I find it using the `/sbin/service` command?

Comment: What desktop environment are you running?

Comment: @Gilles I am not running any desktop. My CentOS 6.4 based server boots to runlevel **3** and stays there. I am basically facing ae problem similar to the one described [here](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2009-March/073465.html).

Comment: That thread points to a tip involving a deamon named [gnome-volume-manager](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/HAL), but I have no such file in my CentOS 6.4 system. What replaced it?

Comment: I believe the daemon that's automounting is part of the desktop, when in runlevel 3 this facility won't be available.

Comment: If you're system is running in runlevel3 you most likely don't have any of the Desktop RPMs installed.

Comment: I found the new name of gnome-volume-manager BTW. It's called `gnome-disk-utility` in CentOS6, I just confirmed that that RPM is in the default yum repos. This U&L Q lead me to it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9067/7453. Do a `yum search gnome-disk-utility*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have commented I don't believe this is possible in runlevel3. The application in question under GNOME 2.x is called `gnome-volume-manager`. You can reconfigure it a bit using `gnome-volume-properties`.

#### screenshot

[image: ss of gnome-volume-properties]

Given you're in runlevel 3 I don't believe this is an option. You could however coax udev into doing the mounting for you in a similar fashion.

**1.** add a file `automount.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d`

**2.** add the following lines to automount.rules

#### automount.rules

```
# automounting usb flash drives
# umask is used to allow every user to write on the stick
# we use --sync in order to enable physical removing of mounted memory sticks -- this is OK for fat-based sticks
# I don't automount sda since in my system this is the internal hard drive
# depending on your hardware config, usb sticks might be other devices than sdb*
ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sdb*", RUN+="/usr/bin/pmount --sync --umask 000 %k"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sdb*", RUN+="/usr/bin/pumount %k"
ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sdc*", RUN+="/usr/bin/pmount --sync --umask 000 %k"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sdc*", RUN+="/usr/bin/pumount %k"
```

**3.** reload the udev rules:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

#### gome-disk-utility

I found the new name of `gnome-volume-manager` BTW. It's called gnome-disk-utility in CentOS6, I just confirmed that that RPM is in the default yum repos.

This U&L Q lead me to it: [USB storage devices aren't automatically mounted when inserted on a fresh install of Debian 6.0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9067/7453).

Do the following command to find it:

```
$ yum search gnome-disk-utility*
gnome-disk-utility-devel.i686 : Development files for gnome-disk-utility-libs
gnome-disk-utility-devel.x86_64 : Development files for gnome-disk-utility-libs
gnome-disk-utility-ui-devel.i686 : Development files for gnome-disk-utility-ui-libs
gnome-disk-utility-ui-devel.x86_64 : Development files for gnome-disk-utility-ui-libs
gnome-disk-utility.x86_64 : Disk management application
gnome-disk-utility-libs.i686 : Shared libraries used by Palimpsest
gnome-disk-utility-libs.x86_64 : Shared libraries used by Palimpsest
gnome-disk-utility-ui-libs.i686 : Shared libraries used by Palimpsest
gnome-disk-utility-ui-libs.x86_64 : Shared libraries used by Palimpsest
```

#### References

- [automounting usb flash drives on linux with udev and pmount](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/automounting+usb+flash+drives+on+linux+with+udev+and+pmount)

Comment: Wow. If I had 4 more points I would've upvoted you. But for now I can only accept. Thank you!

Comment: Youre quite welcome. Glad I was able to help you out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A good command-line method for doing automount is the 'autofs' package.

You need to specify two things, in two different files:

/etc/auto.master

```
# USB backup drives
/mnt/offsite            /etc/auto.offsite       --timeout=300
```

/etc/auto.offsite

```
OFFSITE1 -fstype=auto,rw,noatime,data=journal,commit=1 :/dev/disk/by-uuid/b5c1db0d-776f-499b-b4f2-ac53ec3bf0ef
```

The result is that when the USB drive is attached, it will appear at /mnt/offsite/OFFSITE1.  It will not show up until you access something under that path, such as doing a "ls" or "find".  After 300 seconds of inactivity, it will automatically dismount the file system (making it safe to remove).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use pmount. It seems a little easier to use commonly. However it requires installing (from the EPEL repository).

[CentOS Forum on pmount](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9460)